# How to delete element from canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs

How to delete element if it's not in the canvas area. 
I mean if coridnates left top are minus.

```
canvas.on({
    'object:moving':


});
```

Comment: redraw the canvas and leave that element out

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `redraw()` like this;

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]; //get the canvas dom object
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); //get the context
var c = {
  //create an object to draw
  x: 0, //x value
  y: 0, //y value
  r: 5, //radius
};
var redraw = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear canvas
  ctx.beginPath(); //draw the object c
  ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  requestAnimationFrame(redraw);
};

function move() {
  var x = Math.random(); // this returns a float between 0.0 and 1.0
  c.x = x * canvas.width;
  c.y = x * canvas.height;
}
redraw();

setInterval(move, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas width="250" height="150"></canvas>
```

Check it [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r4JPG/2/) example.

Answer (score 0):

Can use object property isOnScreen
https://jsfiddle.net/i_prikot/4dkb2em3/

```
canvas.on("object:moving", function (e) {
    const { target } = e;
  
  if (target.isOnScreen() === false) {
    canvas.remove(target);
    canvas.discardActiveObject();
  }
});
```